# Remove Items from webpage by comparing it with a List (Python)

Tags: python, list, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

> I have gathered the data in a list which needs to be removed , the below code shows the list :

```
keyword= "www.indigo.com"
hrefs = [links['href'] for links in getDetails.find_all('a', href=True) if target in links['href']]
print(hrefs)
```

> It prints the following output :

```
['https://www.indigo.com/registration.html']
[]
['https://www.indigo.com/buservfcl.html', 'https://www.indigo.com/2021/07/agents.html']
```

> `getDetails` has the complete page source code

> Now, how do I compare `getDetails` with the `hrefs` list and remove/decompose every items that is present in the list.

> I tried this , but it doesnt work for some reason :

```
hrefs = [links['href'] for links in getDetails.find_all('a', href=True) if target in links['href']]
print(hrefs)
for z in hrefs:
    getDetails.decompose()
```

> It removed the entire data in the getDescription, but i need to remove only the elements which are in the list and not evrything

> The output should be the complete HTML except the ones that has [www.indigo.com](http://www.indigo.com) in it

Comment: What is the output that you seek?

Comment: @alphaBetaGamma The output should be the complete HTML except the ones that has www.indigo.com in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to find `parent` tag and then use `decompose()` method

```
html="""<div><a href="www.indigo.com"></div>"""

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")

target= "www.indigo.com"
href_tags = [links for links in soup.find_all('a', href=True) if target in links['href']]

for i in href_tags:
    i.parent.decompose()
```

Output:

`soup` will be empty

From the URL:

```
import requests
res=requests.get("https://www.assamcareer.com/2021/06/oil-india-limited.html")
soup=BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
target= "www.assamcareer.com"
tags = [links for links in soup.find_all('a', href=True) if target in links['href']]
for i in tags:
    i.parent.decompose()
```

Updated Answer:

```
for title in root:
    /
 
        Your code

    /
    href_tags = [links for links in getDetails.find_all('a',href=True) if target in links['href']]
    print(href_tags)

for i in href_tags:
    i.parent.decompose()
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decompose' , this is the Output. How to fix it

Comment: can you provide url or part of html it will be easy to understand

Comment: Yes, sure here it is : https://www.assamcareer.com/2021/06/oil-india-limited.html  , here i am trying to remove assamcareer.com , please check it Sir

Comment: Please check my updated answer it deletes tag in `soup`

Comment: Its the same, still getting this error : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decompose' , Am i missing something  , also res.text is not needed Sir, i am deleting from the html code

Comment: is your tag list is empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239113/discussion-between-edward-and-bhavya-parikh).

Comment: no, the tag list has items